# How do I display last week data from Postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have two inputs that capture startDate and endDate. I have set a default date for both of it. However, my output where not reflecting to it.

ISSUE:
eg. today is 2022-11-09
and I want my output to be last week's data. Hence the output will be from 2022-10-31 - 2022-11-06.

I have seen something similar to my questions but it is not what i want.

I have tried writing this code but is not working for **...**:

```
var customFilter = filter.CustomFilter;

            if (customFilter is { StartDate: { }, EndDate: { } })
            {
                var startDate = customFilter.StartDate.Value.Date;
                var endDate = customFilter.EndDate.Value.Date;
                Truck = (customFilter.StartDate.HasValue && customFilter.EndDate.HasValue)
                    ? Truck.Where(c => c.TransactionStartDate >= startDate && c.TransactionStartDate <= endDate)
                    : **Truck.Where(c => c.TransactionStartDate == startDate.Subtract(1, "week").StartOf("isoweek") && c.TransactionEndDate == endDate.Subtract(1, "week").StartOf("isoweek"))**;
            }
```

Comment: @JonasH i want to display my data based on the condition which the data will only display last week data (from Monday to sunday)

Comment: @JonasH ermm.. basically, before that line of condition, there are these 2 line which capture from the frontend jquery and past it to the backend component. 
``` 
var startDate = customFilter.StartDate.Value.Date;
var endDate = customFilter.EndDate.Value.Date;
```

I'm wondering if I'm able to use this date to filter out my data manually by subtract the data and display last week data

Comment: _"filter out my data manually by subtract the data and display last week data"_ - as a rule of thumb, it is going to be _almost always_ better (footnote) to filter at the database level. (footnote) where "better" == less data to transmit && most databases are built to make highly efficient query optimizations for you == faster (usually)

Comment: @Fildor do you know how to filter based on what i want?

Comment: Not based on the information given in the question. Do you use some sort of ORM?

Comment: @Fildor yes

Answer (score 1):

As @Fildor commented, you may use this `where` clause in native SQL:

```sql
where startDate >= date (date_trunc('week', current_date) - interval '1 day')
  and endDate <= date (date_trunc('week', current_date) - interval '1 week 1 day')
```

Comment: may i know what does that 'date" is?

Comment: See [Postgress Date functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: You may look at it as a constructor or cast of `timestamp` type to `date` type. Another syntax is `cast (<expression> as date)` or Postgresql-specific shorthand `<expression>::date`; These three are equivalent `date <expression>`, `cast (<expression> as date)` and `<expression>::date`.

Comment: ermmm.. i actually want my code to be more into c# rather than sql

Comment: I am afraid that the code in C# will be a lot slower and more complex.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm ermm.. is there any other way for me to display the filter data based on the default startDate and endDate?

Comment: My C# is not strong enough. Sorry.